# Vuetify v-btn routing active class issues

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm writing a CRUD app using Vue with Vuetify.  I have some links defined as v-btns using the "to" attribute.  I've noticed that when clicking on buttons, the active button usually changes so that the button corresponding to the user's current location is highlighted.  However, I have two routes that look like this:

> "/songs/new" 
>   "/songs"

The v-btn's have the following "to" attributes:

> to:"/songs/new" 
>   to:"/songs"

However, when clicking on the button that directs to "/songs/new", vuetify sets both buttons to be active.  Any idea why it does this?

Comment: Never-mind.  If anyone else stumbled on the same issue, I realized the problem was I needed to add the "exact" attribute, otherwise the "active" class is applied inclusively based on the route name.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to make use of **exact** attribute.

```
<v-btn to="/songs/new" exact>Songs</v-btn>
<v-btn to="/songs" exact>New Song</v-btn>
```

Now the button will get active class only if you were in exactly route.

Also you can make use of **exact-active-class** to use custom active classes.